# How to Get Public Data or Tags from Instagram Using the New API?

Tags: ajax, api, instagram, public

Is there any way to get Instagram public profile data as per new API?

According to Instagram, these are the steps that I need to follow:

- Create an application by providing site url and redirect url.
- Redirect your user using oAuth and generate access token.
- Now using the proper url and access token we can get user data.

I did each step and generate access token properly now I am using ajax to hit the url

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/searchq='+inst.instagramId+'&access_token='+inst.accessToken
```

where `inst.instagramId` is user id and `inst.accessToken` is access token.
Response contain code 200 that is ok but data is empty.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Actually with the new Instagram api it is impossible to get public data or tags. The only information you can get with instagram's new api is your data, or access token's owner data.

Comment: Thanks for your help but  I already succeed in getting my own data.

Comment: yea it is impossible getting information that is not yours with the api but ive heard there is other ways that dont use the api

Answer (score -1):

I wrote a proxy API for this exact purpose: https://github.com/whizzzkid/instagram-proxy-api

Let's take an example of #nyc:
Instagram's tag explorer: https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/nyc

Getting the same results as JSON: https://igpi.ga/explore/tags/nyc/media

You can find more examples in the repo. Here is the code that does all this: https://github.com/whizzzkid/instagram-reverse-proxy/blob/master/app.js

A demo application using jquery will be:

```
$.ajax({
  url: "https://igpi.ga/explore/tags/yyc/media",
  dataType: "jsonp",
  data: { count: 3 },
  success: function (json){
    for(var i in json.posts) {
      var img = document.createElement("IMG");
      img.src = json.posts[i].display_url;
      document.body.appendChild(img);
    }
  }
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/4oCwpbMm6p9cyJb1UWld?p=preview

hope this helps.